# Backstack Fragment

Tags: android, fragment, back-stack

I have a problem with Fragment.

I create a main_activity and add a listFragment in it. When I click on one item of listfragment I open a new fragment. I want to add listfragment to backstack, but when I click back button I exit the application. This is my code of on click event:

```
  @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    /*    if (null != mListener) {
            // Notify the active callbacks interface (the activity, if the
            // fragment is attached to one) that an item has been selected.
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(DummyContent.ITEMS.get(position).id);
        }
*/
        jsonitem item = this.listFragment.get(position);



        Fragment newFragment = new descrizione_fragment();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("evento_id",item.getTitle().toString());
        newFragment.setArguments(bundle);
        final android.app.FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, newFragment);


        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();

        //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), item.getTitle() + " Clicked!" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Comment: All Fragment-to-Fragment communication is done through the associated Activity. Two Fragments should never communicate directly. http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Comment: ok thanks but this is why the backstack is not working?